# fill the combobox with the column names

Tags: vb.net, excel

i have an application on vb.net with file Excel

First, i have a button "browse" which open a workbook Excel.

Second ,i  have a button "get the names of the sheets" which give me the name of the sheet in a combobox1 ,then i choose the sheet.
Then i have an other button " get the column names " which give me the name of the columns of the table in a combobox2 .
When i select the name of the column a new sheet add named the name of the column and which has the data of this column

what i want is :

when i choose another  sheet from combobox1, the combobox2 will be refresh with the new columns names  of the new sheet

```
           Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet = CType(Chargement_de_données.xlWorkBook.Sheets(Chargement_de_données.ComboBox1.Text), Excel.Worksheet)
    Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    Chargement_de_données.xlApp.Visible = True

    Dim key As String = CStr(DirectCast(ComboBox2.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)).Key)
    Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox2.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)).Value

    DataGridView1.Visible = True

    Dim DoesSheetExists As Boolean = False

    For Each xs In Chargement_de_données.xlApp.Sheets
        If xs.Name = value Then
            DoesSheetExists = True
        End If
    Next
    If DoesSheetExists = True Then
        MsgBox("L'indicateur est déja ouvert ", CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle))
    Else
        With Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet

            Dim lastrow As Integer = Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet.Cells.Rows.End(XlDirection.xlDown).Row
            Dim colletter As String = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(CInt(key))

            exWS2 = DirectCast(Chargement_de_données.xlWorkBook.Sheets.Add, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
            exWS2.Name = value

            Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet.Range("C1:C" & lastrow.ToString).Copy(exWS2.Range("A1"))

            Chargement_de_données.xlWorkSheet.Range(colletter & "1:" & colletter & lastrow.ToString).Copy(exWS2.Range("B1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it right if I say your worksheets each contain tables with the names of the columns in the first row of the sheet and you wish to retrieve the names of these columns after you select the sheet from the combobox?

Comment: that's what i want would you help me with a code ? please

Comment: Something like this might work for you:  
Public Sub FillColumnCombobox(sheetname As String)  
Dim currentcell As Range  
    ColumnComboBox.Clear  
    
    For Each currentcell In Worksheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells  
        If currentcell.Value <> "" Then  
            ColumnComboBox.AddItem currentcell.Value  
        End If  
    Next  
End Sub

Comment: where i will add this code on the button code or the combobox code to be useful for me ?

Comment: Add the sub to the code behind your form.  
Call the sub in the selectedindexchanged event of the combobox containing the sheetnames. Use the value of this combobox for the parameter sheetname.

Comment: would you explain more for me and tell my how can i call the sub please because i don't know? i'm sorry

Comment: No problem. Just paste the code behind the code you posted. You should have or create a procedure Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged. In this procedure you put the line  
FillColumnCombobox ComboBox1.Value  

Now the list in Combobox2 should be updated if the selection in Combobox1 is changed.

Comment: i get this error :''Error 1 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'."
in this line:             FillColumnCombobox(Chargement_de_données.ComboBox1.Value)

Comment: Sorry, VB.net of course... SelectedValue should work

Comment: i fixed it but the same problem still exist: the msgbox will be shown when i select another sheet and i select from the combobox 2    

FillColumnCombobox(Chargement_de_données.ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value)
 MsgBox("L'indicateur est déja ouvert ", CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle))

Comment: It is a bit tricky for me doing this without using a proper VB.NET application operating on a Excel workbook.... So have some patience with me :-) Could you try ComboBox1.Text and see if that will work.

Comment: Public Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        FillColumnCombobox(Chargement_de_données.ComboBox1.Text)
    End Sub


                                        same problem the msgbox always shown :(((

Comment: Just to be sure: your form is in the VB project right?
What is the message you are getting exactly?

Comment: yes my form is in vb.net
 and this is the msgbox ;'' If DoesSheetExists = True Then
        MsgBox("L'indicateur est déja ouvert ", CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle)) ;'''

just i want when i select another sheet and then i select an item from combobox2 the msgbox don't shown i means when i select a new item the msgbox don't shown

Comment: I think I figured out where things are going wrong. When you clear the Combobox2 or add new items to it, the SelectedndexChanged event is also raised. If you add a local variable to your form (or even better a property) of the type boolean and call it "updating" for instance can set the value to true before reading all the columns (at the start of the FillColumnCombobox sub) and reset it to false afterwards (at the end of the sub) In the SelectedIndexChanged event of the Combobox2 you can add at the beginning if updating then exit sub. This may do the trick